# Obtain Precision and Recall from Click through data

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, precision-recall, average-precision

I am trying to build a graph of precision and recall using click data. I have two data sources.

1. First data source has all the user clicked item_ids based on a given query_id.
2. Second data source has all the item_ids that are shown for the user for a given query_id.

I used python and put these in two data sources into dictionaries as follows:

```
>>> print clicked_data
{101: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 103: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]}

>>> print all_relevant_data
{101: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], 103: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]}
```

I was reading the article in scikit-learn web site (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_precision_recall.html) and tried to follow the formula but got really confuse really setting up False Positive and False Negative.

following the equations in scikit-learn: According to above example prevision for item `101`

```
P = T_positive/ (T_positive + F_positive)

>>> float(len(clicked_data[101]))/float(len(all_relevant_data[101]))
0.5555555555555556
```

But as I try to figure out Recall I am having trouble in getting False Negative items of click data. In theory False Negative means incorrectly marked. All I have is user clicked data for a given id and all the items that are relevant to that id.

```
R = T_positive / (T_positive + F_negative)
```

How can I calculate precision and recall by correctly identifying True Positive, False Positive, and False Negative?

In a train-test enviornment I can go ahead and do precision and recall but when given only the results as:

**query 101** got clicks for following `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` items out of [0, 1, `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` items, getting necessary terms bit unclear (TP, FP, FN).

On a different note if this is not a good metric to evaluate the results, considering the fact that I only have above mention data what would be the good metric?

PS: I am not asking *how to code*, you are welcome to give an example but explanation on identifying TP, FP, FN would be great.

Comment: I have trouble understanding what "relevant" means. Can you describe the process a little bit (background is sometimes also helpful) ? Are all relevant items returned with the query and the user clicks only on a subsample ?

Comment: I edited the question a bit. What I meant by relevant is that lets say user type query `"a"` and all the results shown to user or available to user from that query is `[k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t]` the list. That was what I meant by relevant. And out of that user click `[k,l,r]`